# how do I know the size of my graphics window?

Tags: java

I'm working on these graphics projects in Java, and I need to align things to the base of my graphics window...the problem is that I'm on a mac and I can resize the window and if I minimize and reopen the window, it is just the size I had made it earlier.  How do I determine the "true" height of the graphics window I'm working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the size of the window, you can call `getSize()` on the `Window` object (of which your `JFrame` is a subclass). If you are interested on understanding the new size of your window when it gets resized, you can implement `ComponentListener` and receive `ComponentEvent`s via the `ComponentResized()` callback.

Comment: What if the only thing you have is the `Graphics2D` or `Graphics`?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but one can cycle through a window's parents until no parent remains, this is then your root window, which you can then retrieve the dimensions from.

To get screen resolution you need to refer to the Toolkit class

```
Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

[Java Toolkit API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html)

I tried...

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to center a component on a screen

```
public static void centerComponentOnScreen(Component component) {
    assertNotNull(component, "The component cannot be null");
    // Center on screen
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (int) ((d.getWidth() - component.getWidth()) / 2);
    int y = (int) ((d.getHeight() - component.getHeight()) / 2);
    component.setLocation(x, y);
}
```